# Duplicate declaration of method viewDidAppear and startTimerMethod

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

i am trying to use this code multiple times for different view controllers  however i keep on getting the same error .Duplicate declaration of method viewDidAppear and Duplicate declaration of method startTimerMethod . Can you please tell me how to fix this ASAP . thank you in advance .

the code is here

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startTimerMethod];
}
- (void) startTimerMethod {
    transitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) transitionView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewTransition" sender:self];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startTimerMethod];
}

- (void) startTimerMethod {
    transitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionView2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) transitionView2 {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewTransition2" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: What code? It looks like you tried to add a screenshot, but aren't allowed. Please edit your question to include the code as text (this is preferred to a screenshot of code anyway)

Comment: Methods are declared multiple times in the same class and you're wondering why you're getting a "duplicate declaration" error?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete these below three method one time which you have declared two times-

```
  - (void) startTimerMethod {
transitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
      }

 - (void) transitionView {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewTransition" sender:self];
  }

  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self startTimerMethod];
   }
```

Comment: Thank you that does work . But could you tell me how to use this code on multiple view transitions . When i just copy and paste it and change the identifier I get a error saying duplicate declaration of method viewDidAppear and start timer method